# 'React/RCTAnimationType.h' file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

When trying to build my react native app using Xcode I get the following error: **'React/RCTAnimationType.h' file not found**. I am following and doing exact thing as written in https://documentation.onesignal.com/v5.0/docs/react-native-sdk-setup but still I cannot see why I get that error msg.

I am using 0.54.2 react native version.

Anyone knows what is this error related to? what I am missing?

Comment: Add `$(inherited)` to your header search paths and see if it works?

Comment: @MRFrhn its already defined by default!